# Inline block doesn't work in internet explorer 7, 6

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, css

I have this CSS code with an `inline-block`. Can anyone tell me how to make it work in Internet Explorer 6 and 7. Any ideas? Maybe I'm doing something wrong? Thank you!

```
#signup {
   color:#FFF;
   border-bottom:solid 1px #444;
   text-transform:uppercase;
   text-align:center;
}
#signup #left {
   display: inline-block
}
#signup #right {
   background-image:url(images/signup.jpg);
   border-left: solid 1px #000;
   border-right: solid 1px #000;
   display: inline-block; 
   padding:1% 2%
   width:16%;
}
#signup #right a { font-size:100%; font-weight:bold } 
#signup #right p { font-size:90%; font-weight:bold }
#signup a:hover  { color:#FFF; text-decoration:underline }
```

Answer (score 182, accepted):

In IE6/IE7, `display: inline-block` only works on elements that are *naturally* inline (such as `span`s).

To make it work on other elements such as `div`s, you need this:

```css
#yourElement {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

`*display: inline` uses a "safe" CSS hack to apply to [only IE7 and lower](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/safe-css-hacks#css-hacks).

For IE6/7, `zoom: 1` provides [hasLayout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html). Having "layout" is a prerequisite for `display: inline-block` to always work.

It is possible to apply this workaround while keeping valid CSS, but it's not really worth thinking about, particularly if you're already using any vendor prefixed properties.

[Read this](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) for more information about `display: inline-block` (but forget about `-moz-inline-stack`, that was only required for the now ancient Firefox 2).

Comment: I've read (but cannot test) that you should set `_height: ###px` as well, which is only understood by IE6 and below. Assuming you still care about a browser that is officially dead, that is.

Comment: A good article around this issue, also covering Firefox 2 and IE5.5 & 6: http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

Comment: A caveat of using these hacks as such, is that we don't know how future browsers will parse the preceding asterisk. I'd rule for using conditional IE statements for a separate style-sheet which would facilitate these hacks.

Comment: @JackWilliams: All sensible "future browsers" will have unit tests to prevent that ever being a problem. [Here's](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/LayoutTests/css2.1/t040103-escapes-02-d.html?rev=142904#L1) a random WebKit one, for example. You don't need to worry, no new browser is ever going to accept properties with junk prepended.

Answer (score 2):

`*display:inline` works fine as **IE7 hack**. But, you can add `zoom:1` to the code as `*background:#fff; *display:inline; zoom:1`. Here, you can put your background color code. Sometime, you will not see the layout on the screen, say, for example, list-items will not appear on screen. Then, in such cases this works great and appear as it does in other browsers.