# How do I make the lower two divs be on the same line?

Tags: css, layout

http://jsbin.com/egobu3

I tried putting display:inline, but this had the side effect of shrinking the divs. Basically I want one wide bar, and two narrower areas below that will together be the same size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply add `float: left` to `.b` and `.c`.

```
.b, .c {float: left}
```

http://jsbin.com/egobu3/2

---

Alternatively, add `display: inline-block` to `.b` and `.c`:

```
.b, .c {display:inline-block}
```

And remove the whitespace in the HTML:

```
<div class="b">BBBB</div><div class="c">CCCC</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/egobu3/3

Comment: Or have [one `float: left;` and the other `float: right;`: JS Bin demo](http://jsbin.com/egobu3/4/).

Comment: Be careful with the use of `inline-block` as IE6 doens't support it and IE7 may have some [issues](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html)

Comment: @Brombomb: Thanks, I should have mentioned that in my answer. Both IE6 and IE7 can be coerced into working. See a recent answer of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838454/inline-bloc-internet-explorer-7-6/5838575#5838575