# make divs appear side by side

Tags: css, css-float, inline, html

I am restructuring my tabular format data to show in divs. When I am assigning a css `display:inline-block;`, the divs are displaying side by side in IE8 but in IE6, its coming downwards.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you actually have "tabular data" you should be using a table.

Comment: You cannot use "inline-block" in IE6 as it is not supported!
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Comment: As an update: Luckily, IE6 usage is down to 0.6% in the US and most of the rest of the world.  Unless you are specifically targeting China, it can safely be ignored at this point.

Answer (score 4):

To make `display: inline-block` work in IE6, use this:

```
selector {
     display: inline-block;
     *display: inline;
     zoom: 1
}
```

Why does this work? See: [Inline block doesn't work in internet explorer 7, 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838454/inline-block-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-7-6/5838575#5838575)

---

> I am restructuring my tabular format
>   data to show in divs.

I have to agree with the other comments - that is a **bad idea**.

You *should* use a `<table>` for tabular data - that's what they're for, semantically!

Comment: Actually, in my current page, the div above the tabular data is not showing any scrollbar. So I was advised to convert the tabular data to divs, the header as a separate header div and the data table as a separate div.
If there is a way to show a scrollbar on the table's parent div, I would be more than happy.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `display: block; float: left` to achieve that in IE6. But be aware of the box-model problems with IE6 and the usage of `width` and `padding`.

But as a side note, if you have real tabular data, you should use `<table>`. There is no need to switch to `<div>` for that task.

Comment: Actually, in my current page, the div above the tabular data is not showing any scrollbar. So I was advised to convert the tabular data to divs, the header as a separate header div and the data table as a separate div. If there is a way to show a scrollbar on the table's parent div, I would be more than happy.

Comment: You should have had this information within your question. You could set the table parents div to a fixed height i.e. `height: 600px` and `overflow-y: scroll`, so the table parents div will have a vertical scrollbar.