# Is it possible to position divs beside eachother and center them?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I'm dynamically generating more divs (of same size with same content), and I want them side by side and also center them.

Example:
Assuming there can be 4 divs on one line I want it do look this:

1 div: `...[]...`

2 divs: `..[][]..`

3 divs: `.[][][].`

4 divs: `[][][][]`

5 divs:
`[][][][]

...[]...`

Is this possible?

I know you can put multiple div's in one line (and let them wrap) with `float:left` and an outer container with `width: 100%`

Test here: http://jsfiddle.net/Tyilo/cD7e3/1/

Comment: Could you add the tag for which language you're using to dynamically create these divs so we can better assist you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, that's possible:

http://jsfiddle.net/pRNgH/

I included the hacks required to make `display: inline-block` work in IE6/7, for more info:

[Inline block doesn't work in internet explorer 7, 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838454/inline-block-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-7-6/5838575#5838575)

You need to ensure that you don't output whitespace between the `.dynamic`s, or [this happens](http://jsfiddle.net/pRNgH/1/).

**CSS:**

```
.divHolder {
    width: 400px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    margin: 0 0 16px 0;
    text-align: center
}
.dynamic {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #ccc;

    display: inline-block;
    /* make it work in ie7 */
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="divHolder">
    <div class="dynamic">2</div><div class="dynamic">2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to place all divs in a wrapper div and use text-align:center; for the wrapper div.

#### EDIT:

Check out Marty's comment he's right.  You would also need to do display:inline-block; for inner divs.

Comment: I don't think text-align: center applies to block elements (divs).

Comment: Display: inline-block is for block elements with widths based on their content.. So if set widths are required then this won't work either hehe :P

Comment: @Marty Wallace - If look at his question it clearly states "of same size", we can safely assume that the SOer is setting dimensions :P

Comment: You have the right idea. See my answer for an implementation.

Comment: Hm, I'd normally use float: left and display: block for columns, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Revised based on your comment:

If you're creating them dynamically then why can't you do:

```
parent width = totaldivs * div width;
parent margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: I don't want the divs to stretch. They should have a fixed width