# Css, How do I set the width of an container

Tags: css

Css question here: How do I set the width of a container just wide enough for how many characters are in the container?

Thanks for your help, -Matthew

Answer (score 2):

`display: inline-block` is an easy way to do this.

`float: left` is another option.

Make sure an explicit `width` is not being set, because that will disable the shrink-wrap behaviour.

http://jsfiddle.net/5jyAg/

Comment: It's funny, I usually say that myself. Anyway, you're correct. If IE7 is a concern, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838454/inline-block-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-7-6/5838575#5838575

Comment: ..and the comment vanished into the ether.

Comment: It should be noted that < IE7 does not support inline-block on inline elements. (PS: I wasn't sure about it being < IE6 instead so I decided to remove the comment :)

Answer (score 1):

it depends on the container, if you use a `span` as the container, it will always be as wide as the characters in it.

but a span is inline element

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put and even Padding into your style.  For example if your markup looks like this.

```
<div>
     <p class="paddThis">Your text</p>
</div>
```

and in your style sheet set the padding of the right and/or left of the text your text will push the left and right border of your container a certain amount of pixels away from you text creating which should accomplish what you are trying to do.

Your style sheet might look like this

```
.paddThis
{
   padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
```