# Another centering DIVs within a fixed DIV question

Tags: css, html, centering

I am attempting a very simple procedure here, basically trying to center the client logos within this main clients div. I've just recently started with this web design business and while I can read some of the solutions out there, I'm having trouble applying them to my structure.

Basically I have a few client boxes, each is going to have a PNG image inside of them:

```
            <div id="clients">
                <div class="client-box">CLIENT LOGO</div>
                <div class="client-box">CLIENT LOGO</div>
                <div class="client-box">CLIENT LOGO</div>
                <div class="client-box">CLIENT LOGO</div>
                <div class="client-box">CLIENT LOGO</div>
            </div>
```

I'd like to be able to center the client-box's on the client's div that has a fixed weight. I've tried using **display: inline-block** but that didn't seem to do much. I'm assuming that's because I've already forced them to **float: left** but I don't know how I can maintain their position in the div without doing so. Like I said I'm quite a novice with CSS and this is what I've been doing for all my CSS.

Here's what I have for clients and client-box CSS:

```
           #clients {
           background-image: url("img/images/clients_bg.png");
           border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
           border-top: 1px solid #666666;
           float: left;
           margin-top: 120px;
           padding: 10px;
           width: 778px;
           }
           .client-box {
           background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #bcb546;
           float: left;
           font-family: verdana;
           font-size: 11px;
           height: 60px;
           margin-right: 10px;
           opacity: 0.8;
           padding-top: 40px;
           text-align: center;
           width: 100px;
           }
           .client-box:hover {
           opacity: 1;
           }
```

From my understanding, this shouldn't be hard to achieve, but so far I have not had any luck probably because my brain is fixated on a certain way of doing things and it just won't budge. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You can see the live site [here](http://www.shazamprojects.org/demo/wbrs/).

Thank you SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've tried using display: inline-block
>   but that didn't seem to do much.

`float: left` forces `display: block`, so `display: inline-block` would have no effect.

On `.client-box`, you need to:

- remove `float: left`
- add `display: inline-block`.

Finally, on the parent element (`#clients`), you need to add `text-align: center`.

[image]

Comment: No problem. If you need this to work in IE7, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838454/inline-block-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-7-6/5838575#5838575

Comment: @Stratego: I rejected your suggested edit because in this case, the gaps seem to be desired.

Comment: Unfortunately this mechanism seems to break the moment I put an <img> inside the div. It somehow changes height and knocks everything out of proportion. I was forced to change everything back to its original state for the time being until I find a solution for this. I'd appreciate it if you can help me with this. I've tried forcing height="100" and width="100" on the <img> but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @Andy Hassan: That's a common problem with `inline-block`. This is the first and last time that you're going to have that problem though - there's an easy fix. Add `vertical-align: top` to whatever has `display: inline-block`. For details on why this is required, read the "baseline" section here: http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

Comment: Why does this work? Does inline-block somehow make a div equal to text, so text-align: center does something?

Answer (score 2):

If your outer div is of a fixed width you can set the margins for the inner div to take up the appropriate space. 
eg:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        stuff
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer { width: 600px; }
.inner { width: 400px; margin-left: 100px; margin-right: 100px; }
```

Alternatively you can use margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; however that (like everything else in the world) doesn't work in IE.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I will add a wrapper to the client-boxes, whose width is equal to the total width of client-boxes.

For example, in the live site you post above, there are 5 client boxes, and each of them are 100px width with 10px margin-right. So add a div wrapper with width 5 x (100 +10) = 550px, and center the wrapper with "margin-left:auot" and "margin-right:auto".

```
<div style="width: 550px;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">

                <div class="client-box">CLIENT LOGO</div>
                <div class="client-box">CLIENT LOGO</div>
                <div class="client-box">CLIENT LOGO</div>
                <div class="client-box">CLIENT LOGO</div>
                <div class="client-box">CLIENT LOGO</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works but the logos are subject to change as some will be taken out others will be added in and doing that much math everytime seems a bit troublesome. I've used @thirtydot 's solution for now but will keep yours in mind. I appreciate you taking the time to write this solution yzandrew.

Comment: One thing you might come across with thirtydot's solution is that "display:inline-block" is not working with IE7. define a class like 
.myInlineBlock {
 
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:top;
 /* For IE 7 */
 zoom: 1;
 *display: inline;
}

Comment: Unfortunately his solution is not working at all when I add an <img> inside the div.