# CSS: positioning question

Tags: css

I have container did and there are many divs inside that div.

In one of those divs I need to place 5 small icons and all of them are individual form submit buttons...

the main problem is I want all these icons in one line and in the middle of the div could someone guide me how to achieve this..

something like this http://jsfiddle.net/pJMva/60/

Thanks
all efforts appreciated

Comment: could you post the code that you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/dYaCw/1/ (works in IE6+)

Answer (score 1):

place them in a span called "submitbuttons", then do this in css:

```
submitbuttons { margin: 0 auto; }

submitbuttons input { display: inline-block; }
```

Presuming you are using input elements of course.

Comment: inline-block is not supported in MSIE6 and not even completely in MSIE7. I wouldn't use that.
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Comment: @Andreas Carlbom http://jsfiddle.net/pJMva/61/ this doesnt work.... may be I did something wrong .... could you tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: @Omeid Herat: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838454/inline-block-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-7-6/5838575#5838575

Comment: You weren't prefixing the ID with #, and since you are using forms, THEY need to be display: inline-block. Otherwise </form> always results in a linebreak. Check out the this: http://jsfiddle.net/pJMva/86/

Comment: @thirtydot: that is not only _display: inline-block;_

Comment: @Omeid Herat: You said `"inline-block is not supported in MSIE6 and not even completely in MSIE7"`. While that statement is *strictly* true, it's *very misleading*, because it already works on `inline` elements and you can make it work on `block` elements with 2 extra lines.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ahallicks/pJMva/62/

Comment: the images are in a single line but what about centering them??

Comment: Sorry about that, didn't read the question well enough. Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/ahallicks/pJMva/87/