# no-wrap issue in IE 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, nowrap

HTML:

```
<ul id="popular-tags-hidden">
<li id="tag-1"><a class="display-new-tag" href="#">Tag 1<img width="10" height="10" src="http://www.communr.com/images/add-tag.png"></a></li>
<li id="tag-2"><a class="display-new-tag" href="#">Tag 2<img width="10" height="10" src="http://www.communr.com/images/add-tag.png"></a></li>
<li id="tag-3"><a class="display-new-tag" href="#">Tag 3<img width="10" height="10" src="http://www.communr.com/images/add-tag.png"></a></li>
<li id="tag-4"><a class="display-new-tag" href="#">Tag 4<img width="10" height="10" src="http://www.communr.com/images/add-tag.png"></a></li>
<li id="tag-5"><a class="display-new-tag" href="#">Tag 5<img width="10" height="10" src="http://www.communr.com/images/add-tag.png"></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul#popular-tags-hidden li {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 3px 6px 3px 0;
}

a.delete-new-tag, a.display-new-tag {
    float: left;
    background: #e2f2ce;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #466840;
}
```

IE 7 Result:

[image: IE 7 Issue]

Desired Result:

[image: Desired Result]

The tags get cut off on the right side of the ul container. I have tried researching the problem and I think it has something todo with the padding, but I can't figure it out. Works in all browsers except IE7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to fix it is to switch from `float: left` to `display: inline-block` on the `li`s.

It's less hassle if you do this for only IE7:

```
ul#popular-tags-hidden li {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 3px 6px 3px 0;

    /* just for ie7 */
    *float: none;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1
}
```

Compare:

`float: left` (as you had it): http://jsfiddle.net/cqSUy/

`display: inline-block` for only IE7: http://jsfiddle.net/CfXq6/

---

About `*display: inline; zoom: 1` - [Inline block doesn't work in internet explorer 7, 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838454/inline-block-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-7-6/5838575#5838575)

In short, it's how you say `display: inline-block` for IE7.

Comment: +1: floats are horrible; I always prefer `inline-block` over `float`.

Comment: No problems with floats, but this type of CSS hack with asterisks, etc. is bad news.

Comment: @doublejosh: `*` is fine, and is widely used. For example, [making `display: inline-block` work in IE7](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/b261f97/less/mixins.less#L42) (example from Twitter Bootstrap). Also, read this: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/safe-css-hacks#safe-css-hacks.