# Two unordered list side by side

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have two unordered list and I am trying to place them side by side.
This works in Firefox, Safari and Chrome & IE8. But not IE 7 or compatibility mode.

Here's the markup:

```
<span>
   <ul style="list-style-type: none; display: inline-block;">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
   </ul>

   <ul style="list-style-type: none; display: inline-block;">
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
   </ul>
<span>
```

Basically the expected is:

```
1  3
2  4
```

Comment: `float:left;` them maybe? (with second having left margin)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

IE 7 doesn't deal with `inline-block` properly. See http://flipc.blogspot.com/2009/02/damn-ie7-and-inline-block.html for details, but in brief, add the following styles to your lists:

```
zoom:1; *display: inline; _height: 30px;
```

Answer (score 6):

In IE6/7, `display: inline-block` only works on elements that are naturally `inline` (e.g. `span`).

For block-level elements (such as `ul`), you have to whip it into shape:

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/yw8uZ/

```
ul {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1
}
```

I've gone into more detail about this in the past, see: [Inline block doesn't work in internet explorer 7, 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838454/inline-block-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-7-6/5838575#5838575)

Comment: I forgot to mention it in my answer, but I changed your outer `span` to a `div`. A `ul` is not a valid child of `span`, so your HTML was invalid.

Answer (score 5):

You could `float` them.

```
   <ul style="width:10%; float:left;">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
   </ul>

   <ul style="width:10%; float:left;">
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
   </ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/K3xcg/

Comment: True, though I don't really like the width:10%. Also you'll have to either use clear:left on the following element or use a clearfix (google it) on an element which would contain both lists.

Comment: @khel.  The width can be set to whatever.  It is only for example.

Comment: when the list on the left has more items than the list on the right.  The right list does not start from the top or not align on the top with the left.  any fix for this?