# CSS set width on items in centered horizontal list

Tags: html, css, layout, internet-explorer-6, html-lists

I have a horizontal list which I'm using as a paging control.

I have two additional requirements - I need to **specifiy the width of some of the items**, and I need to be able to **center the list in the page**. I can do one or the other, but I can't work out how to achieve both.

See the below as an example/starting point:

```
<ul>
    <li class="previous"><a>previous</a></li>
    <li><a>1</a></li>
    <li><a>2</a></li>
    <li><a>3</a></li>
    <li><a>4</a></li>
    <li class="next"><a>next</a></li>
</ul>

li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 5px;
}

a
{
    padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px;
    border: solid 1px #aaa;
    color: #131313;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shooter/ZdsLu/1/).

I would like the `previous` and `next` items to be the same width, and I would like the whole thing centered in the page. Note that I can't know the width of the complete list, so using a container with `margin: 0 auto;` isn't going to work afaik.

Must be cross-browser and support IE6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**See:** http://jsbin.com/azoquv

- `text-align: center` on `ul` centers the whole thing.
- `display: inline-block` and [the hack for IE6/7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838454/inline-block-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-7-6/5838575#5838575) allows you to set your own `width` on `li`.

Tested in IE6/7 + Chrome. It will just work in all modern browsers.

```
ul {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
li
{
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;

    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 5px;
}

a
{
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px;
    border: solid 1px #aaa;
    color: #131313;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: this might be a stupid question, but is there any reason you have a extra line break after `zoom`? Is that part of the IE hack?

Comment: No, it's not part of the hack. You can remove the line break if you like.