# Replace an image with a Flash object without blinking

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

Let there is a (display:inline) image on a white background:

```
<a href="#"><img src="..."></a>
```

Then I replace the IMG node with an Youtube IFRAME using JavaScript. The image disappears and the white background is shown to user for a second while the Youtube clip is being loaded.

The problem: I don't want that dark-white-dark blinking.

I tried to set A's background to color black, but just a small part of the rectangle was filled with the color (because A is not a block element).

Is there a way to avoid the blinking? The inline nature of the elements must be preserved. It's better if no additional HTML elements would be introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to set A's background to color black, but just a small part of the
>   rectangle was filled with the color **(because A is not a block
>   element).**
>
> Is there a way to avoid the blinking? **The inline nature of the
>   elements must be preserved.**

Try `display: inline-block` on the `a`.

Comment: You're welcome. If you happen to still support IE6/7, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838454/inline-block-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-7-6/5838575#5838575