# Wrapper Div and Inner Div center align

Tags: html, css

Here is my html code looks alike.

```
<div style="width:70%; margin:0px auto; border:1px solid #000;">

<div style="float:left; width:100px; border:1px solid #000;">Test</div>
<div style="float:left; border:1px solid #000;">Test</div>

</div>
```

The output result looks like this.

http://imm.io/7PWG

As you can see, the wrapper div is at the center of the browser but two of the inner div are on the left side. I want them to be in the center of the wrapper div.

Any ways to do it ? Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: This won't help your alignment issue, but I think you need to add a "clear div" after the two inner divs so that the div border is displayed around the inner divs: `<div style="overflow:hidden; clear:both; height:0;"></div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`display: inline-block` can do this in a reasonably simple way:

```
<div style="width:70%; margin:0px auto; border:1px solid #000; overflow:hidden; text-align:center">
    <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; text-align:left">
        <div style="float:left; width:100px; border:1px solid #000;">Test</div>
        <div style="float:left; border:1px solid #000;">Test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/LJaDd/

- I wrapped a new `div` around your inner two `div`s, and gave it `display: inline-block`.
- I added `text-align: center` to the outer `div` to center the wrapper `div`, then added `text-align: left` to the wrapper `div` to align the text inside back to the left.
- I added `overflow: hidden` to the outer `div` so that it [contains the floated `div`s](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59).

Comment: thanks, it's works except IE, seems like inline-block is not working cross browser ?

Comment: It only works on naturally inline elements in IE6/7, but fortunately it's easy to fix, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838454/inline-block-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-7-6/5838575#5838575). Here's a fixed version of the demo in my answer that does work in IE6/7: http://jsfiddle.net/LJaDd/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be helpful: http://www.pmob.co.uk/pob/centred-float.htm

Answer (score 0):

try this ...

```
<div style="width:70%; margin:0px auto; border:1px solid #000; background-color: yellow;">
    <div>
        <div style="float:left;width:100px; border:1px solid #000;">Test</div>
        <div style="float:left;border:1px solid #000;">Test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the float:left was causing your inner 2 divs to go all the way to the left and not be centered. By putting those inside another div that fixes it.

here it is in action ... http://jsfiddle.net/sixgun/mp3T2/