# Horizontal Lists without floating the LI

Tags: html, css

Okay, so I'm writing CSS for a navigation bar that uses an un-ordered list to organize the menu. The menu is centered not pushed to any side, and the width of any given li element cannot be pre-determined (it varies with how much text is in the menu item), so I can't hardcode widths.

I have the following CSS code:

```
#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    height:16px;
}
#nav ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial,STHeiti,'Microsoft YaHei',sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

for the nav element, and this works perfectly to produce the centered nav-menu in Chrome 13. But when I view the page in IE8, the UL turns vertical and I can't get it to become horizontal.

So far, search results indicate that I need to `float:left;` or `float:right;` the <LI>s to make the menu horizontal. I've tried this and it does make the menu horizontal in IE8 but it will float to left or right. I need to center the menus, and apparently there is no `float:center;`.

The HTML corresponding to the menu is

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="current_page_item">[LINK]</li>
        <li class="page_item">[LINK]</li>
        <li class="page_item">[LINK]</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Is there any way without needing to know the width of the LIs or having to resort to JS to get the menu centered AND horizontal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code works fine in IE8, see for yourself:

http://jsfiddle.net/bEEEb/

It's probably not working for you because you're not in IE8 Mode (IE7 Mode or Quirks Mode are the alternatives).

Add a doctype as the very first line if you don't have one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

If you need this to also work in IE7 (in which `inline-block` only works with naturally inline elements by default), then [replace `display: inline-block`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838454/inline-block-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-7-6/5838575#5838575) with:

```
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
zoom: 1;
```

..of course, if you can get away with `display: inline`, that's the simplest fix, **but you should still work out why your page is not being displayed in IE8 Mode.**

Comment: I see, thanks for this tip. I'm trying to achieve highest browser compitability.

Answer (score 3):

just use the following on your li:

```
display: inline;
```

Should get you the desire results.

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't support `display: inline-block`, use `display: inline` instead on you li element.