# padding not working in IE7 and IE8

Tags: html, css

I searched all over the web to find a solution for this issue, but I was not lucky. 
I know when it comes to styling web pages for IE is worse than watching grass grow.

So, I have a problem with the padding. It works just fine in IE9 and all other browsers, but it fails in IE7 and IE8. Probably lower versions too (I will check on that later)

Th e UL suppose to be in-line with a back-ground
thanks

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org
 /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>Document sans nom</title>

  <style type="text/css">
   a{font-weight:bold;color:#369;}
   a:link{text-decoration:none;}
   a:visited{color:#936;text-decoration:none;}
    a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}

   .manubar a:link{color: #FFFFFF;}
   .manubar a:visited{color: #DFFFDF;}
   .manubar{
    padding:10px 0 0 0;
    height:26px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
     background-color:#FF8C00;}
    .manubar ul{list-style-type:none;padding:0;margin:0;}
    .manubar ul li{text-align:center;border-left:1px solid 
     #999;display:block;float:left;}
     .manubar ul li:first-child{border:0;}
     .manubar ul li.insert{width:191px;}



     .home{width:94px;}
     .insert{width:94px;}
     .offer{width:94px;}
     .search{width:114px;}
      </style>
      </head>
     <body>

      <div style="height:30px; width:100%;">

      <nav class="manubar">
      <ul >
      <li class="home"  >
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="insert">
        <a href="insert.php">Post</a>
    </li>
    <li class="offer">

    <a  href="offer.php">Offer</a>
    </li>
    <li class="search">

        <a  href="searching.php">Search</a>
    </li>


    </ul>
     </nav>
      </div>

      </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: You forgot to tell what problem it is that you have.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid (look where the `body` tags are), don't blame IE.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=html5+shiv&oq=html5+shiv&aqs=chrome.0.57j65j59l2j61l2.4380&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: It was just a typo mistake. That didn't solve the problem. Thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [nav](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/nav) tag is introduced in HTML5. So obviously it will not support in older browsers. Replace `nav` tag with `div` tag to make it work. (Check browser compatibility section in the provided link)

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rS5WG/1/)** (Replaced `nav` with `div`)

**or else**

Stick the below code in the Head tag

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script>
      document.createElement('nav');
  </script>
<![endif]-->

<style type="text/css">
  nav{ 
       display: block;
  }
</style>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8779603/1577396)

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rS5WG/2/)**

Comment: Or add an html5 shiv to create the elements needed via JS to allow older IEs to style them. https://www.google.com/search?q=html5+shiv&oq=html5+shiv&aqs=chrome.0.57j65j59l2j61l2.4380&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: in my opinion, dont use nav element, until 2015. if you do, dont style it, put a div inside it too and style it instead. why would you need it anyway.

Comment: @user1721135 - I've used those elements in every website I've ever created…

Comment: @Rich Bradshaw that just means youre pretty new :P

Comment: I did back port things, but yeah, in the scale of things I'm new, only been doing it about 7 years.