# IE 7-8 Css html mistake

Tags: html, css

http://ucuzarakip.com/Kategori/Oyuncak-Kategoriler/Ahsap-Oyuncak/15

Please check this page in IE7 or IE8. I could not find where is the mistake. it works on Firefox and Chrome with no error.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using HTML5 elements. To make those elements work in IE7 and IE8, add the below code in your head tag

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script>
      document.createElement('header');
      document.createElement('nav');
      document.createElement('section');
      document.createElement('article');
      document.createElement('aside');
      document.createElement('footer');
      document.createElement('hgroup');
  </script>
<![endif]-->

<style type="text/css">
  header, nav, section, article, aside, footer, hgroup{ 
       display: block;
  }
</style>
```

(*Remove the HTML5 elements which you are not using or add the which you are using in the above code*)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8779603/1577396)

Answer (score 0):

You're using HTML5 elements without a [HTML5 shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/).

IE7 and 8 do not support tags like `nav`, `header`, `section`, etc.