# Having problem aligning 3 items in an <li>

Tags: html, css

Im having trouble aligning 3 elements in a list.

Here is the link to my problem:

http://mistirio.com/codecanyon/beta_flexi/

I the only way i could fetch those sliders and their labels in the correct form is by using :
    float: left; to each element.

But that puts them on the left of the page. Which is pretty obvious.

Doing nothing messes it up.

All help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `float: left` with `display: inline-block`. The `text-align: center` that you have on a parent element will then center the sliders.

If you need IE6/7 support, use `display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1`. [More info.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838454/inline-block-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-7-6/5838575#5838575)

Comment: That did it.! Thanks a lot.. In 9 minutes ill be allowed to mark this as read :)

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to wrap them all then align to the right. ie:

```
<ul style="width:500px; text-align: right;">
    <li>Foo<input /></li>
    <li>Bar<input /></li>
    //etc...
</ul>
```

Comment: I thought of that, but that actually messes up my original stylesheet, so i have to keep the structure the same.. If you refresh now, you will see the original stylesheet.

My concern was, what happens if someone removes the stylesheet.
Thirtydot's answer fixed this..

Comment: New design is much better, and my solution is ill-designed for this. Glad you got your answer =)