# how to set the width on an inline element?

Tags: css

I have this css:

```
.test {
    background-color:#00ff00;
    display: inline;    
    width: 200px;
}

<div class="test">test1</div>
<div class="test">test2</div>
```

But it seems that the width is not read. How to change the css?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`inline` items cannot have an explicitly set width.  Use `inline-block` instead.

```
.test {
    background-color:#00ff00;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Note, though, that IE 6/7 have compatibility issues with `inline-block`, it doesn't apply properly to elements that are block-level by default. These issues [can be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838454/inline-block-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-7-6/5838575#5838575).

Answer (score 0):

We cannot set width for `inline`.
But if we use `inline-block` we cannot place child elements in one row
So please use `inline-table`.
This is style that I have tested

```
.test {
    background-color:#00ff00;
    display: inline-table;
    width: 200px;
}
```

I have checked this. Use `display:inline-table`.
It works well.