# How can I make a centered, left-aligned, variable-width bullet list with CSS?

Tags: css, list, centering

Is it possible somehow to center a left-aligned list? Like, I want the list itself centered, but want the bullet points to line up below each other.

I know I could sort of do this if I give the list a fixed width and margin auto, but I really don't want to set a width on it since I don't know how wide the content will be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` on the `ul`, and `text-align: center` on a parent element.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/E3Yjr/

**CSS:**

```
.list-container {
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="list-container">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item Looooooooooooooooooooooooonggg</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you need it to [work in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838454/inline-block-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-7-6/5838575#5838575), here's how: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/E3Yjr/1/

```
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
zoom: 1;
```

Comment: What a smart idea, kudos. [Won’t work in IE 6 & 7 or Firefox 2](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/display%3Ainline-block), but other than that, you’re golden.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: Cheers. `display: -moz-inline-stack; display: inline-block; zoom: 1; *display: inline;` [would make it work](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) in IE6/7 + Firefox 2 (but nobody cares about Firefox 2 any longer).

Comment: aha, yes — I remember reading that article and not being able to get `-moz-inline-stack` to work, but I don’t think I noticed how to get `inline-block`-style behaviour in IE 7 and 6. Great stuff. (And I entirely agree re Firefox 2.)