# Center variable-width floated element

Tags: css, css-float

The element has a variable width, so I don't know it.

Is it possible to center this element inside its wrapper element?

The wrapper has a fixed width of 960px...

Comment: Close enough: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9019019/405015

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `text-align: center;` to the wrapper, and then `display: inline-block;` to the child

Or add `display: table;`  and`margin: 10px auto;` to the child element

Or `position: relative; left: 50%; float: left;`

Comment: <div style="text-align:center">  
      I wanted the paragraphs to left align, so I reset here  
      <div style="display:inline-block;text-align:left">  
        <p> ... </p>  
        <p> ... </p>  
        <p> ... </p>  
      </div>  
    </div>

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as you have `margin:0 auto;` with the variable ***width specified***...

Comment: thats the problem, i can specify the width because depends on the text inside the element..

Comment: you could write some `JS` that, on page load, retrieves the `outer width` and sets the `CSS` style property to the `outer width` detected in the script

Comment: depends on the element containing the text but using `<p>` or `<div>` will work with this solution without additional js, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qGKDb/1/) is an example where the width is randomly set

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/traMU/