# Vertical-align div in relation to auto height div

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

I am trying to make vertical-aligned div in relation to auto height div.
It is a little bit hard to explain so I have screenshot that will explain everything:

[image]

The **orange** div is the **container**.
The **blue** div is **2nd container inside the main container**.
The **green** div is the **vertical-aligned** div which should be aligned in relation to the blue one.

I have no idea how to make this work. I want it to be cross browser (ie6+, ff & chrome).

Thank you very much!

Comment: You haven't explained anything about width. What is the width of each of those three elements?

Comment: The left one is 500 and the second is 248. Does it really matter? I will change it as soon as I get the principle...

Comment: It would have mattered if your answer was "the green div is 200px and the blue div should take all the remaining space, the orange div is the width of the screen". That would have made it more difficult (especially considering you want IE6 support..). But, if everything is fixed width as you said, it should be quite easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/aeFrH/

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    width: 748px;
    background: orange;
}
#container-inside {
    width: 500px;
    background: cyan;
}
#aligned {
    width: 248px;
    background: green;
}
#container-inside, #aligned {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="container-inside">
        Some<br />
        content<br />
        is<br />
        in<br />
        here.<br />
    </div><div id="aligned">
        Aligned.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll explain this later. Tested in Chrome, IE7. Should work in IE6.

Comment: Works perfectly. Waiting for your explanation. I never used css property with *. Thank you very much.

Comment: In IE6, there's a 1px space line in the container. Fixed it using your answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/5078297#5078297

Comment: There are two significant things I have to explain here. **1.** due to the use of `inline-block`, the whitespace between `</div>` and `<div id="aligned">` is significant; ideally there shouldn't be any. **2.** `display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1;` is [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838454/inline-block-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-7-6/5838575#5838575).

Answer (score 2):

For this answer I have assumed that both the blue as the green divs have a **dynamic height**.

In order to calculate the correct offset of the **green** div we can **not** use CSS. CSS doesn't allow us to position an element using the data of another element.

Instead, we need to calculate the offset ourselves which requires a client-side language. Time to embrace Javascript. To make it easier for us, I'll use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) because it does a lot of work for you using real sweet syntax.

So, we need to find out how to calculate the offset. First we need to know the center of the **blue** element. Easy enough: `blue.height / 2`. Next, we need to calculate how much the **green** div should go **up** when the top of the **green** div is aligned the actual center of the **blue** div. That's basically the half of the height of the **green** div, right? That gives us the next formula: `(blue.height / 2) - (green.height / 2)`.

Alright, let's put that in javascript!

```
var center = $('div.blue').outerHeight(true) / 2; // this is the blue div
var offset = center - $('div.green').height() / 2;
```

And finally, setting the offset:

```
$('div.green').css({
    'margin-top': margin
});
```

Cool theory, but I'm sure you want to see it in action. You can see the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5ufaS/).

---

Edit:

Oh yeah, I forgot to mention that jQuery is a cross-browser framework and supports very, very old browsers.. Read all about it [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility)!

Comment: I dont want javascript solution. I forgot to mention that... Anyway this is a good solution for those who want to use javascript.

Comment: Well I prefer Javascript over CSS hacks, but glad you found a proper answer!