# Center <img /> + <a /> inside table and overflow auto in IE7

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am having a problem centering an image and a inside a table. At the moment I have set `display: inline-block` which works on in everything apart from IE7.

Also I have set a parent `<div />` with `overflow-y: auto`, the problem with this is that in IE7 the table is behind the scroll bar, where as in FF the scroll bar is at the side of the table. Is there any way to get around this problem?

[This is a simplified version:](http://jsfiddle.net/D52Uv/15/)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/D52Uv/10/

To fix the scrollbar problem, perhaps the easiest "fix" is `*padding-right: 20px`, which will apply in only IE6/7. Adjust `20px` to whatever looks best.

To fix the image:

```
.image {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E7E7E7;
    border: 1px solid #C7C7BB;

    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;

    margin: 4px 2px 0 0;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: center;
}
.image img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[More info here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838454/inline-block-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-7-6/5838575#5838575)