# Distributing images evenly & horizontally in a Div via CSS

Tags: css, html

I'm having a difficult time finding specific info for my case. I'd like to distribute 3 image thumbnails across a 940px div in order to line up with the rest of my content. So far, I've gotten the images to line up horizontally, but the spacing is off & everything is shifted left.

**Here is my CSS:**

```
#thumbs {   
  width: 940px;
  margin-top:90px;
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

**My HTML:**

```
<div id="thumbs">
  <a id="single_image" href="/dev/images/1.png">
    <img src="/dev/images/thumb1.png" alt=""/>
  </a>
  <a id="single_image" href="/dev/images/2.png">
    <img src="/dev/images/thumb2.png" alt=""/>
  </a>
  <a id="single_image" href="/dev/images/3.png">
    <img src="/dev/images/thumb3.png" alt=""/>
  </a>
</div>
```

**Example Images**

**What I currently have:**

[image]

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

[image]

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Each of your `a` elements has the same ID. IDs should be unique.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use the technique shown in my answer here: [Fluid width with equally spaced DIVs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/fluid-width-with-equally-spaced-divs/6880421#6880421)

Here it is with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/JTcGZ/

**CSS:**

```css
#thumbs {   
    width: 540px;
    margin-top:90px;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;

     text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
}
#thumbs a {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="thumbs">
    <a id="single_image1" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
    <a id="single_image2" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
    <a id="single_image3" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
    <span class="stretch"></span>
</div>​
```

Comment: With a little bit of tailoring, your code works! The #thumb width: was a little off, I changed it to 940px,

Also, on #thumbs a, the line "*display" needs to be corrected to "display"


(Just for future readers)

Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. I changed `940px` to `540px` simply to make it fit more easily in the jsFiddle window. `*display` is part of a hack to make `display: inline-block` [work in IE7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838454/inline-block-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-7-6/5838575#5838575). If you don't need to support IE7, you can safely remove `*display: inline; zoom: 1;`. Lastly, if my answer was what you wanted, could you [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)?

Comment: Actually, because `a` is an inline element, you can probably get rid of the whole `#thumbs a { .. }` rule.

Comment: The downside is there must be a space between each inline-block, and no space between last one and closing tag of parent element.

Comment: @Ali thanks for the tip that there needs to be a &nbsp; between each element. I wasted too much time until I saw that comment.  thirtydot, you might want to mention that in your answer.

Comment: @FrazerKirkman: There does need to be *some* whitespace, it doesn't necessarily have to be `&nbsp;`. You only need explicit `&nbsp;`s if you're using JSX (or similar) that strips this type of whitespace.

Answer (score 36):

The answer is very simple, just use:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
```

That's all!

Comment: Great solution. Works when you want responsive images as well.

Comment: Does not work - .container does not exist within the OPs HTML tag

Answer (score 30):

There is an clean solution:

http://radiatingstar.com/distribute-divs-images-equaly-line

```
#container {
    text-align: justify;
}
#container > div {
    width: 100px; /* Declare your value. Can be in relative units. */
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#container:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Underrated answer in my opinion. I tried them all and this one is very clean and very effective. The only issue is: if I have, let's say, two rows and 7 thumbnails, the first row will display evenly 5 thumbnails and the second row will display two thumbnails dispatched at the extreme positions, leaving the middle of that row completely empty which ruins it a little. It would have been perfect if the two last thumbnails in the second row were aligned to the left (or right). Your solution is too even for a classic gallery…

Comment: Strangely, this solution is whitespace sensitive, at least in Firefox 42.0 and Chrome 46 under Linux.  See https://jsfiddle.net/3fxjxay6/  vs https://jsfiddle.net/r97umtdw/  Headscratching!

Answer (score 3):

Try add

> position:relative; text-align:center;

in #thumbs, and set width and margin for  (or img) within #thumbs.

Something like this, testing various values:

```
#thumbs a {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0 4%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The downside of `text-align: justify;` is this that you there must be space between each two inline-block elements, otherwise those two elements will stick to each other.

you can check this behavior here:
http://jsfiddle.net/JTcGZ/1552/

The new modern way to achieve this is to use flex.

```
#thumbs {   
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between // flex-start | flex-end | center | space-around;
    align-items: stretch // flex-start | flex-end | center | baseline;
}
#thumbs a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Also you can define percentage width in modern browsers:

```
#thumbs a {
    width: calc((100% / 3) - 10px);
}
```

please visit this this page for more detail on flex layout:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: For some reason the top method stretched the vertical height of my images?

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards Actually it's a great feature of flex layout that can stretch all items to be the same height, but you can control it using align-items style of flex container, just set it to flex-start! I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

why wouldn't the wrapping id div thumbs be used as a container with a top padding of 90px, and the other internal elements use a simple class (not an id so it can be reused), that all float left.  that way they horizontally align perfectly, and also the wrapping container provides the margin you are looking for.  you'll also use considerably much less code to accomplish what you want.