# list item blocks background-image of parent div by expanding background-color to 100%

Tags: html, css

It seems that when an element has display:block, the background-color of that element extends to 100% of the width of the parent element (as it is intended). I would like instead for the background-color to extend only to the edge of the text, so that the parent element's background-color is visible. I would use a float or inline-block, but it is also important that each element exist on a new line.

CSS Code:

```
body {
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#1a1a1a;
    font-family: inconsolata;
    font-size:13px;
}
#content {
    position:absolute;
    width:50%;
    left:25%;
    top:5%;
}
.entry {
    /*background-color: #1a1a1a;*/
    background-image:url('images/stripe3.png');
    color:#f00;
    /*padding:1px;*/
}
ul {
    display:block;
}
li {
    background-color:#fff;
    margin-left:20px;
    padding: 0px 4px;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="entry">
        <ul>
             <li>
             the illuminator : ongoing : projection, social practice
         </li>
         <li>
             color organisms : 2014 : projection, net art
         </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ***background-color applied only to the text*** so just use `color` instead? or you mean the background-color affected area should be shrunk close to the text as much as possible?

Comment: Please rephrase your question, seems a little unclear

Comment: You mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/UeP3f/ ??

Comment: NOTE: // is not valid for css comments

Comment: // has always worked for me as long as it's inside the code brackets

Comment: @prismspecs improve your question, its not clear what exactly you want.

Comment: @prismspecs: did you see the fiddle i linked to? is that what you want?

Comment: prismspecs: @Lost is right, listen to him please. `//` is not standard and is a hack. `/*..*/` is standard. Reference: [(here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Comments) and [(here)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#comments). Also, take time to read [(this)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298890/is-it-bad-practice-to-comment-out-single-lines-of-css-with).

Comment: abhitalks, thank you. it is close, however i don't want an arbitrary distance from the right side of the container but rather for the background-color to come to the right edge of the text of each line item, does that make sense?

Comment: @prismspecs what is close? LOL, what *abhitalks* said was about the use of `//` to comment in CSS, which is invalid. That's all. Not related to your actual problem in this question. For your question, No it still makes less sense.

Comment: @KingKing um... his jsFiddle demo is close to what I want to achieve. Please don't post spam.

Comment: @prismspecs it's not spam, it's just a misunderstanding, in fact his demo was posted some comments above the last comment of him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that you have a pure text node inside the `li` which is difficult to select in CSS.

It is more **common** for text to be wrapped in some form of text tag such as a `p`, `span` or commonly in a list item an anchor tag `a`.

Thusly;

```
<div class="entry">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">the illuminator : ongoing : projection, social practice</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">color organisms : 2014 : projection, net art</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

In this way, you can just target the anchor tag directly like so

```
.entry {
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    color:#f00;

}
ul {
    display:block;
}
li {
    background-color:#fff;
    margin-left:20px;
    padding: 0px 4px;
}

li a { /* select anchor tag */
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

However, this might restrict the clicking area of your link so one might decide to make the anchor tag `display:block` also...and we're back where we started.

So, wrap the text again in an inline element such as a span and target that instead.

**Revised HTML**

```
<div class="entry">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><span>the illuminator : ongoing : projection, social practice</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><span>color organisms : 2014 : projection, net art</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Revised CSS**

```
.entry {
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    color:#f00;

}
ul {
    display:block;
}
li {
    background-color:#fff;
    margin-left:20px;
    padding: 0px 4px;
}

li a {
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: block;
}

li a span  { /* like this */
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Final Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/8QMvr/5/)

Finally, if you wish to see the background of the `ul`, remove the background colors from the `li` and `a` - like this - http://jsfiddle.net/8QMvr/8/