# Squarespace div positioning with custom CSS

Tags: html, css, position, positioning, squarespace

I'm helping a friend with her website, which she created in squarespace... she simply wants the three home page images to be overlapping... the images are located in several divs inside of divs. I'm trying to do a hack where I put absolute positioning on the divs so I can position them where I want them and also overlap them, and it works when I'm looking at the site in firebug, but once I add the custom code in squarespace, it doesnt work! Frustrating... Does anybody have success in squarespace with inserting your own CSS in order to manipulate positioning of divs?

Here is the website:
http://www.marciahindsadg.com/

And here is the code that works for me in firebug, but not once I put it in squarespace's custom css section:

```
<style type="text/css">

<!--- Film image block -->
#yui_3_17_2_1_1423953053128_228 {
    left: -110px;
}

<!--- Television image block -->
#yui_3_17_2_1_1423953253236_246 {
    right: 150px;
    top: -20px;
}

<!--- Fantasy image block -->
#yui_3_17_2_1_1423953253236_211 {
    z-index: 100;
    left: 550px;
    top: 115px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: The images have inline styles which have higher importance/priority than external styles.  My guess is squarespace has js that is determining the position of these images.

Comment: You could use !important to override this.  Example: right: 150px !important;

Comment: I've actually tried using !important; next to every line, but that doesn't seem to work either :(

Answer (score 1):

Remove the HTML comments. They don't belong to a CSS style tag. That's why your CSS is not valid.

Use CSS comments instead -> `//Test comment`.

Comment: Those single line comments don't belong in CSS either! Use `/* Comment */` instead.
Source: [Is it bad practice to comment out single lines of css with //](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298890/is-it-bad-practice-to-comment-out-single-lines-of-css-with)

Comment: Thanks!!  You are right... the html comments were messing it up. I replaced the html comments with CSS comments.   ALSO... I realized in the squarespace code, in order to manipulate any div, you have to dig through the code to find the OUTERMOST div within that image that you want to move. The code was a bit ridiculous... like 5 nested divs just for one image!... and once I changed the code to manipulate the outermost divs (and once I fixed the commenting code), it works now!!  THANKS FOR YOUR HELP! :)