# Div won't display at 100% width in div with id #portofolio

Tags: html, css

All the other div settings work, but when using classes .l100 and .p100 , the image doesn't display.

I tried rearranging the style for .l100 and .p100 after the others, but it makes the .l75 and .p75 dissapear...

Can anybody help with this, here's the code:

```css
* {
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
    }
    
    #portofolio {
     width: 80%;
     margin: auto;
    }
    
    .image {
     background-size: cover; 
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position:center;
     
     position: relative;
     
     margin-bottom: 1%;
     margin-right: 1%;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     
     /*-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 58px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
     -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 58px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
     box-shadow: 10px 10px 58px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);*/
     
     float: left;
    
    }
    
    //portrait 
    
    .p100 {
     width: 99%;
     padding-bottom:  177.77%; 
     margin-right: 0%;
    
    }
    .p75 {
     width: 74%;
     padding-bottom:  133.33%; 
    
    }
    
    .p50 {
     width: 49%;
     padding-bottom:  88.88%; 
    
    }
    .p25 {
     width: 24%;
     padding-bottom:  42.1%; 
    
    }
    
    
    //landscape 
    
    .image.l100 {
     width: 99%;
     padding-bottom:  56.25%; 
    
      
    }
    
    .l75 {
     width: 74%;
     padding-bottom:  42.1875%; 
    }
    
    .l50 {
     width: 49%;
     padding-bottom:  28.125%; 
    }
    
    .l25 {
     width: 24%;
     padding-bottom:  14.0625%; 
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    
    
    <div id="portofolio">
    
    <!--<div style="width: 100%; height: 400px; overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x:visible;margin-bottom: 2vh;">-->
    <div class="image p25" style="background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/jJ4rNF/g7_XLRx_E2_crop.jpg);"></div><!--https://image.ibb.co/cdpKba/g7XLRxE.jpg-->
    <div class="image l75" style="background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/dVGMpv/329_Flower.jpg);"></div><!--</div>-->
    
    <div class="image l50" style="background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/dgwkhF/20170501_135937_DARKER_CROPPED.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="image l50" style="background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/h1WPba/ezgif_com_crop_PROBABLY_THE_BEST.gif);"></div>

    
    <div class="image l100" style="background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/fJL4ba/20170604_222345.jpg);"></div>
    
    </div>  
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's your comments that are causing those classes to be skipped. `//` is not valid comment syntax.

If you change them from `//comment` to `/* comment */`, the classes work:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FIE6CZSCPO09

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218808/do-double-forward-slashes-direct-ie-to-use-specific-css#answer-11218889