# CSS floating (can't get clearfix to work)

Tags: html, css, css-float

I can usually fix all floating-related issues by using a clearfix style, but I can't get this one to work. I have tried adding a clearfix style to the right column. I'd rather not use a separate clearfix div.

The screenshot below should illustrate the problem:

http://min.us/leRsoGVqAQtbJ

**HTML:**

```
<div class="two-thirds left">

    <!-- Quotes -->
    <div class="notepad">
        <p class="quote">“I have worked [...]</p>
        <span class="who">- Clara Craftsman [...]</span>
    </div><!-- .notebook -->

</div><!-- .two-thirds -->

<div class="one-third right clearfix">
    p>This should be floating to the right of the notepad, but the Work Experience heading should be below.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* Floates*/
.left { float:left; }
.right { float:right; }

/* Quotes */
.notepad,
.quote,
.who {
    display:block; 
    font-family:"Neucha",cursive;
    font-size:16px;
}
.notepad { 
    width:409px;
    padding-top:25px;
    margin-left:30px;
    background:url(../img/misc/notepad/notepad-top-big.png) no-repeat; 
}
.quote {
    width:315px; /* 409px total */
    padding:0 28px 24px 66px;
    background:url(../img/misc/notepad/notepad-middle-big.png) repeat-y;
}
.who { 
    width:315px; /* 409px total */
    padding:0 28px 48px 66px;
    background:url(../img/misc/notepad/notepad-bottom-big.png) no-repeat;
    text-align:right;
    font-style:italic;
    margin-top:-24px;
}

/* Clearfix */
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: you could try `.left, .right { overflow: hidden; }` in your css

Comment: providing you never want content to appear outside normal boundaries, that should provide a fix to the problem that adds the least HTML+CSS (that I can see anyway)

Comment: I also can't see the clearfix you've tried adding to the right column

Comment: If you're problem is _"can't get clearfix to work"_, you should also provide your code for `clearfix`.

Comment: Also, `clearfix` should be applied to the parent of the floating elements, not the floating elements themselves.

Comment: I have edited my post; adding the clearfix style to the right column and the clearfix CSS code.

Comment: Parent.clearfix > child.float

Answer (score 3):

You cannot apply a `float` and `clearfix` to the same element.

From [Here](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html),

> The problem happens when a **floated element** is within a **container box**,
>   that element does not automatically force the container’s height
>   adjust to the floated element. When an element is floated, its parent
>   no longer contains it because the float is removed from the flow.

You should apply the `clearfix` like this :

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="one-third right">
        <p>This should be floating...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that doesn't use floats but inline-blocks instead. See if this is what you are looking for-

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fntce/3/)

Modified css-

```
#wrapper 
{
   min-width:700px; 
}
.left,.right { display:inline-block; }
.left
{
    width:70%;
    min-width:420px;
}
.right
 {
    width:28%;
    min-width:170px;
 }
```

Comment: Well for the older versions of IE. But floats are removed from the normal flow of document. Here's also a good article on why inline-blocks should be used over floats- [Inline-blocks over floats](http://joshnh.com/2012/02/07/why-you-should-use-inline-block-when-positioning-elements/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip and for the article. I really like the idea, but I can't get the font-size zero fix to work so I have a few pixels in between .left and .rigth (one or two spaces I guess...). I could work around this by using 26px margin instead of 30px (or by using the comment fix), but I rather not since I'm creating a theme for hundreds of people to use. I could use these workarounds for a personal project, but i suspect a lot customers will have problems with this - leading to many support tickets for me...

Comment: +1 for what I would recommend. [**IE7 usage is less than 1%**](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201210-201212-bar) so unless it's an internal site that has to work on IE7 I would use `inline-block`. Anyway you can always force IE7 to use `inline-block` if you really want - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838454/inline-block-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-7-6