# Make square divs to occupy whole screen

Tags: html, css

I'd like to make these occupy whole screen horizontally as squares and fit into it. At the moment they fit, because they are inline-blocks, but on certain screen sizes(or if you zoom out a bit) they will leave a <250px space to the right.

I could give them, for instance, `width:25%;`, but how can I make them be squares? How to set the height to be equal to the dynamic width?

```css
.note {
  display: inline-block;
  /*
#F3F389-galben
#96C0FF albastru
#94F1B6 verde
rosu#f40042
     */
  background-color: #f40042;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 0;
}
textarea {
  width: 80%;
  height: 60%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  resize: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: 'Rancho', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="note">
  <textarea placeholder="Your note's text here"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="note">
  <textarea placeholder="Your note's text here"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="note">
  <textarea placeholder="Your note's text here"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="note">
  <textarea placeholder="Your note's text here"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="note">
  <textarea placeholder="Your note's text here"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="note">
  <textarea placeholder="Your note's text here"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="note">
  <textarea placeholder="Your note's text here"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="note">
  <textarea placeholder="Your note's text here"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="note">
  <textarea placeholder="Your note's text here"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="note">
  <textarea placeholder="Your note's text here"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="note">
  <textarea placeholder="Your note's text here"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="note">
  <textarea placeholder="Your note's text here"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Found my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188455/how-to-center-multiple-divs-inside-a-container-in-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know of any possible way using HTML, CSS to do this. You need to use script to set the height of a div/element to be the same as dynamic width

```
var w = $('.note').width();
$('.note').css({'height':w + 'px'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the width in % and then create an equal height by giving the element `padding-bottom: 100%;`.