# Confused about using SPAN vs DIV and natural flow

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have been trying to create a blinking LED with a caption (the relative position between the LED and the caption should be kept at all times) ... I would like the LEDs to be aligned next to each other when the page is wide enough, and to become stacked when the page shrinks (i.e., the LEDs should be responsive).

I am happy with the relative positioning and with the behavior when the page is maximized, but I don't manage to implement the responsive behavior ... I have tried playing around with DIVs, SPANs, inline-block and floating ...

I guess I am confused as to how they interact with each other.

Any suggestions on how to approach/solve this issue?

The CSS is here:

```
.led {
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   border: 2px solid black;
   border-radius: 20px;
   margin: 40px 60px 20px 60px;
   background: #f2ffe6;
  position: relative;
}

.led_caption {
    width: 700%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 30px;
    left: -300%;    
}
```

The HTML is here:

```
<div style=" width: 500px; height: 100px; margin: 0 auto; ">
    <div class="led" style="display:inline-block">
        <span class="led_caption"> Caption </span>
    </div>
    <div class="led" style="display:inline-block">
        <span class="led_caption"> Caption </span>
    </div>
    <div class="led" style="display:inline-block">
        <span class="led_caption"> Caption </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the Codepen link is here: http://codepen.io/vpappano/pen/WGYpzm

---

### *** EDIT

I have (hopefully) used some of the suggestions/recommendations from Kodie Grantham and Damiano Celent. I have created the following structure:

LED -- holds a 'bulb' and a 'caption' -- see below

```
.led_bulb {
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   border: 2px solid black;
   border-radius: 20px;
   margin: 10px 40px 20px 65px;
   background: #f2ffe6;
   position: relative;
}

.led_caption {
    width: 700%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: -300%;    
}

.led {
    width: 160px; 
    height: 70px; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
   .led {
     display: block; 
     margin: 0 auto;
   }
}

@media (min-width: 401px) {
   .led {
     display: inline-block; 
   }
}
```

LED Holder -- holds 2 LEDs -- see below ... The LED holders should show 'next' each other (the screen would show 4 LEDs total), if there is enough room ...

```
/* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188455/how-to-center-multiple-divs-inside-a-container-in-css  */
.led_holder
{
    position: relative; 
    margin: 10px auto; 
    text-align:center;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
   .led_holder {
     /* ??? */
     margin: 0 auto;
   }
}

@media (min-width: 801px) {
   .led_holder {
     /* ??? */
   }
}
```

A single LED Holder is beautifully responsive (2 LEDs ==> 1 LED without a problem).

I am trying to get the same behavior for the combination of 2 LED Holders. The responsive progression would then be: 4 LEDs ==> 2 LEDs ==> 1 LED

I thought I had gotten the hang of it ... but the browser keeps proving me wrong ...

The modified CodePen can be found here ...  http://codepen.io/vpappano/pen/PGxKaB

Thank you  :-)  :-)

---

### *** EDIT  -- FIXED!!  :-)

All,

Thank you for your help and hints .. I fixed the code ...

I initially had

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
   .led_holder {
     display: block; 
     margin: 0 auto;
   }
}

@media (min-width: 801px) {
   .led_holder {
     display: inline-block; 
   }
}
```

but I had forgotten to add

```
.led_holder {
   position: relative;
}
```

:-)  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this you will want to use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

CSS:

```
.led {
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   border: 2px solid black;
   border-radius: 20px;
   margin: 40px 60px 20px 60px;
   background: #f2ffe6;
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
   .led {
     display: block; 
   }
}

.led_caption {
    width: 700%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 30px;
    left: -300%;    
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style=" width: 500px; height: 100px; margin: 0 auto; ">
    <div class="led">
        <span class="led_caption"> Caption </span>
    </div>
    <div class="led">
        <span class="led_caption"> Caption </span>
    </div>
    <div class="led">
        <span class="led_caption"> Caption </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect !!!  Thank you very much ... :-)  :-)   At this point, I am a tad greedier ... May I ask my question here, or do you want me to start a NEW question?  Thank you again ...

Comment: If it's related then go ahead and ask here!

Answer (score 1):

I have added a flexbox solution, as long you don't care about prehistoric and ancient browsers, it's good to go.

Let me politely remind you to not use inline styles in the Markup like you did, just do not do it.

Learn to use media queries:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {}
```

This is the syntax, I would always do it element by element, first establish the large screen default, then follow up with a media query for the element, as some elements don't need adjustments and it's easier to read.

Flexbox is something you will have to read about, everyone will have to, it's the responsive design future technology.

As an old school fallback, you can just resort to displaying elements inline-block for large screens and block for small screens(in your case).

Here is the code:

```
.main{width: 500px; 
height: 100px; margin: 0 auto;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: row;
-ms-flex-direction: row;
flex-direction: row;
-webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
-ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
-webkit-justify-content: space-around;
-ms-flex-pack: distribute;
justify-content: space-around;
-webkit-align-content: stretch;
-ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
align-content: stretch;
-webkit-align-items: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
align-items: center;}
```

This is just the code for the flexbox wrapper, you need a flexbox wrap, this makes the child elements displayed as flex.

Link to pen:

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/gwQWPq

Comment: thank you for your comments, suggestions and for taking the time to do a Codepen example ...  :-)   I was not aware of the "flexbox" ... I shall have to read up on the topic. Thank you again.

Comment: @Vincenzo, 
You're welcome, look here, the browser support table for flexbox:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox
Not to long ago, people designed layout with tables, then came the float, and the present and future are flexbox, maybe css grids, but yes, do check out flexbox, it's not that buggy anymore, it has unified syntax, needs prefixes, but it handles positioning issues with ease.
And now upvote me:-) Cheers mate

Comment: Unfortunately, my reputation in non-existent ... I need at least 15 reputation points to upvote an answer ...  :-(  Sorry ...  :-(

Answer (score 1):

I've changed some html layout like below and use flexbox for this, please have a look

```
<div class="flex_row">
    <div class="flex_box">
        <span class="led"></span>
        <p> Caption </p>
    </div>
   <div class="flex_box">
        <span class="led"></span>
        <p> Caption </p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex_box">
        <span class="led"></span>
        <p> Caption </p>
    </div>
      <div class="flex_box">
        <span class="led"></span>
        <p> Caption </p>
    </div>
      <div class="flex_box">
        <span class="led"></span>
        <p> Caption </p>
    </div>
      <div class="flex_box">
        <span class="led"></span>
        <p> Caption </p>
    </div>
   </div>
```

CSS

```
body{padding:0; margin:0; line-height: 1.1;}
.flex_row
{
     display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
      -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap; /* Safari */
  flex-wrap:         wrap;
   -webkit-justify-content:center; /* Safari */
  justify-content:        center;
   -webkit-justify-content: space-around; /* Safari */
  justify-content:         space-around;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start; /* Safari */
  align-items:         flex-start;
     width: 80%;
    padding: 0 10%;
}
.flex_box
{
    text-align:center;
}
.led {
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   border: 2px solid black;
   border-radius: 20px;
   background: #f2ffe6;
   display:inline-block;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {
  .flex_row
{
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
     width: 98%;
    padding: 0 1%;
}
.flex_box
{
    align-self:center;
}
}
```

For more screens to handle, you need to add more media screens

Comment: thank you for taking the time to show me how to use flexbox... It is greatly appreciated.