# Apply CSS rule to display objects depend of number of objects

Tags: html, css

I have array of object with rule

`{width:10%, float:left,display:block;height:20px}`

If I have 10 objects, it will be displayed in one line,one by one, so its fine. My problem is, if i print less than 4 objects ,I want to display them on center of page, without floating left .... In another case , if I have e.g 33 objects, I want to display 3 full rows with left floating objects, 10 in one row ... and last row with 3 objects must be aligned on center page. Any suggestion how to solve this with css?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center multiple divs inside a container in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188455/how-to-center-multiple-divs-inside-a-container-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

I think I get the idea of what your trying to do and this can be achieved nicely with flex. Take a look at this demo

```css
.container {
  border: 1px red solid;
  width:408px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper on your DIV and center text

```
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Then use `inline-block` to your DIV's items to achieve the desired...

```
.wrapper div {
  width:10%;
  display:inline-block;
  height:20px;
  background: #ff0000;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  }
```

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper div {
  width:10%;
  display:inline-block;
  height:20px;
  background: #ff0000;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  }
```

```html
<h1>4 divs</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<h1>33 divs</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using flex. Use

```
 flex-wrap:wrap
```

to make sure your items wraps whenever it overflows horizontally, then use

```
justify-content:center
```

to center them horizontally. [Plunk here](https://plnkr.co/edit/WYi4nuSFoD7Qn7rNsjIm?p=preview).

Good to know: if you were to encounter aligning/centering vertically, you can use ***align-items: center*** following this approach.

Hope this helps!