# Inline div block with border and padding causes the div to go out of page margin

Tags: html, css

How can I prevent the top edge from being cut off in this code: http://jsfiddle.net/ebW6F/?

HTML code:

```html
<div id="text">
    abcd efgh
</div>
```

CSS code:

```css
#text {
    display: inline;
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do that:

```css
#text {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

Comment: And for some old browsers *display: inline; zoom:1

Comment: @Enve Nice one - I did not know this. Enve is referring, I assume, to this or something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838454/inline-block-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-7-6/5838575#5838575

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to be creating a box of some kind, use `display:inline-block` instead of just `display:inline`.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/ebW6F/2/