# Vertically center inline image without distorting text spacing

Tags: html, image

By default, an image in line with text is bottom-aligned with the bottom of the line, and top-aligned with the bottom of the previous line, which changes the text spacing:

[image]

I'd like to instead center the image on its line of text (e.g. using `vertical-align:middle`), but without distorting the spacing:

[image]

How can this be done in a way which is compliant with most browsers?

As a minimal example, consider this markup:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/38/Rect_Geometry.png/220px-Rect_Geometry.png" style="vertical-align:middle"> with an image </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your markup look like?

Comment: Do you just want to float it?

Comment: @shubniggurath Yes, but float only works for left and right, and I want it to work vertically.

Comment: If your "Ordinary Lines" were longer, you would like them to be behind the image?  Or are they meant to word wrap in a smaller container to the left of the image?

Comment: @BenFelda They would be behind, I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution:

HTML (no change):

```
<p>A line</p>
<p>Another line</p>
<p>Another</p>
<p>Your (possibly) long line <span class="img-container"><img id="image" src="http://image.org/" /></span></p>
<p>One more line</p>
```

CSS (using positioning):

```
.img-container {
    height: 0px;
    position:absolute;
}

#image {
    margin-left: 1em;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 63px;
}
```

Notice both solutions need to know the size of the image.

My solution, (using "position: absolute;") require knowing the width of the image to add text after it.

To do that, we just have to add another span with a padding equal to the width of the image, see codePen: [http://codepen.io/loxaxs/pen/mjFxJ/](http://codepen.io/loxaxs/pen/mjFxJ)

Comment: I actually just found out about this trick myself.  Though perhaps you mean to switch the absolute and relative positions?

Comment: "to switch ... positions". I don't understand. In my code, the "position: relative;", just allow to manually centre the image. (using "bottom: ...px").

Comment: Sorry, I mean making the image container relative and the image absolute.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of no specific places where this is a good idea.  Only, I suppose, if the image is  vertically shorter than the text.  Otherwise, massacre of aesthetics.

Try making the image height 1em.  Or 0.9 em.

Comment: Perhaps if the image is at the end of the longest line of text?  However, good point about resizing the image (though it's not what I'm going to do), +1.

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would do:

HTML:

```
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text <span class="mid-image"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/38/Rect_Geometry.png/220px-Rect_Geometry.png" style="vertical-align:middle" /></span> with an image</p>
<p>Some text</p>
```

CSS:

```
.mid-image {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    height: 1px;
}

.mid-image img {
    margin-top: -75px
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QgutY/1/

And then read: [Inline block doesn't work in internet explorer 7, 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838454/inline-block-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-7-6)

Answer (score 0):

By changing `img` tag position to `absolute` you can fix it.

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JKfQE/1/)

Comment: The image doesn't display inline anymore here.